# CakePHP find from HABTM relation

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I have a table named 'companies'. I want to join this table with 'plans'. I have written following model relation.

```
Company: 
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
       'Plan' => array(
            'className' => 'Plan',
            'joinTable' => 'companies_plans',
            'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'plan_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
        )
    ); 
Plan: 
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Company' => array(
            'className' => 'Company',
            'joinTable' => 'companies_plans',
            'foreignKey' => 'plan_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'company_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
        )
    );
CompaniesPlan:
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Company' => array(
            'className' => 'Company',
            'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Plan' => array(
            'className' => 'Plan',
            'foreignKey' => 'plan_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

Now I want to find from the Company model with join... for that I have written the following code...

```
    $companiesWithPlan = $this->find('all', array('joins' => array(
    array(
        'table' => 'companies_plans',
        'alias' => 'CompaniesPlan',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions'=> array('CompaniesPlan.company_id = Company.id')
    ),
    array(
        'table' => 'plans',
        'alias' => 'Plan',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions'=> array(
            'Plan.id = CompaniesPlan.Plan_id',
        )
    )
)));
```

Then I get only company table data.. I am not sure why it's not working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top bit, where you define your `$hasAndBelongsToMany`'s etc looks OK. It's your bottom query that's off. When you're using CakePHP's built-in associations (hasAndBelongsToMany, belongsTo, hasMany, etc) then Cake will take care of fetching the relationship for you. You don't need to specify any joins yourself. You should read the doco from here down to the bottom of the page: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm

(in particular, note that `hasAndBelongsToMany` associations are deleted and recreated each time a record is saved - make sure that's the behaviour you want)

So, I've told you not to use joins - what you use instead is Cake's [containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html), which allows you to specify which associations will be included when you do a find.

The correct code should look something like this:

```
$this->contain(['Company']);
$this->find('all');
```

You'll also need to make sure to include the containable behaviour at the top of your model:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

I put containable in my `AppModel.php`, because all your models should use it.

PS - the time you'd use joins is when you have a case that is particularly complex and can't easily be handled by Cake's built-in associations - hasMany, belongsTo, etc. Most of the time, you don't need to use joins (Cake will create the joins automatically behind the scenes, when it sees fit).